# JavaScript/CSS/HTML fading and moving elements on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I was looking at the SkyZone website and they had some cool JavaScript/CSS/HTML effects that I wanted to incorporate in my website.

https://www.skyzone.com/ (Home Page)

If you look at their nav bar, when your mouse hovers over a button a line fades in and moves underneath the text.

If you go to the "Our Core Attractions" section, in the attraction boxes you have a "See Details" button with an orange arrow next to it. This arrow moves when your mouse hovers over the button.

If someone could help me make these/similar effects on my website or tell me how it is done I would appreciate it!

Comment: such effects doesn't need javascript, just pure simple css, look for css animations

Comment: you could also use d3 to wire up some transitions https://www.tutorialspoint.com/d3js/d3js_transition.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```css
.nav-item a.hoverbar::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    height: 0.1rem;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.nav-item a.hoverbar:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0.2rem);
}

a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-item a.stretch::after {
    content: '';
    top: 2.4rem;
    right: -0.4rem;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 0.5rem;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 0 0.1rem 0.1rem 0;
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    border-color: black;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.24, 0.97);
}

.nav-item a.stretch:hover::after {
    transform: translateX(100%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="hoverbar nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="hoverbar nav-link" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Stores</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="hoverbar nav-link" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Events</a>
                </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="stretch nav-link" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Get Started</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

</nav>
```

Demo pen: https://codepen.io/siddiquiadeel/pen/vrGdLR

Explanation: The anchor elements on the navbar make use of the **::after** selector to create a pseudo-element on the anchor tag, which initially has the opacity set to 0 so you can't see it. 


There is a pseudo-class **:hover** attached to the anchor element along with another **::after** pseudo-element which works as detecting hover events on the anchor element and adding an element after the anchor element with certain properties. This element is only added when the hover event is detected. 


In this case, the properties are just opacity and the transform for animation. Remember that there is already an **::after** pseudo-element attached to the anchor element with certain properties, so this just works as setting the opacity and transform, so that you can see the ______ floating in below the anchor element. 


The animation for the arrow next to the "Get Started" anchor element works in a similar way.

Read the documentation on MDN for CSS pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover